# Pressing <Down> opens a new tab in Konsole

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, konsole

Since only recently, when I press the <kbd>↓</kbd> (the <kbd>Down</kbd>) key, a new tab is opened in the Konsole terminal emulator.

This is only happens in Konsole, not, for example, in Gnome terminal.

I don't know what changed to make it happen. How can I fix this?

Comment: getting almost the same issue... pressing minus (-) is somehow pressing "up" or "home", as the effect is to scroll far back in my console command history. Super annoying, and shortcuts doesn't list anything obvious. Just started happening too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. <kbd>Down</kbd> key was set as shortcut for a shell profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within Konsole go to Settings > Configure shortcuts > Now look at the New tab or clone tab , maybie PgDown is set as the shortcut, and change it, if that is the problem :)

Comment: No, **Down** is not set as any shortcut..