# KDE Konsole Shortcut to Launch New Tab with different profile

Tags: shortcut-keys, plasma, konsole

I've been trying to figure out how to set a short cut to launch a new tab, with a specific profile, but I can't seem to find an option. Effectively I want to emulate the highlighted Menu option below:
[image]

I can set shortcuts to Profiles in the Manage Profiles Pane, however, that changes the *active* tab's profile; not what I want (and in this case doesn't change the environment to Powershell). I can launch a new tab with a shortcut, but that uses the Default profile.

Nothing in the Configure Shortcuts screen shouts out that it will do this, and a search of *"[Konsole open new tab with profile shortcut](https://www.google.com/search?q=Konsole+open+new+tab+with+profile+shortcut)"* drew me to questions like [Pressing  opens a new tab in Konsole](https://askubuntu.com/q/334540/597903), [Is there a keyboard shortcut to open a new Konsole tab?](https://askubuntu.com/q/117879/597903) and [Switch profile in Konsole from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/416572/597903); none of which address what I'm trying to achieve.

Can you actually set a shortcut for launching a **new** tab for a specific profile in Konsole?

Comment: Please run `qdbus $KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE $KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW newSession` in konsole and tell me if that opens a new tab.

Comment: It does, @danzel .

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

- Disable `"Run all Konsole windows in a single process"` in konsole settings
- install `xdotool`
- Create a global shortcut with the follwing command, replacing `[profile_name]` with your profile's name:

```bsh
qdbus org.kde.konsole-$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool search --class "konsole" | tail -1)) /Windows/1 newSession "[profile_name]"; xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool search --class "konsole" | tail -1)
```

---

There doesn't seem to be a dedicated shortcut for this, and as [this post](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=227&t=161490) suggests, the default behaviour seems to have changed in recent versions.

However, there is a workaround. As explained [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=227&t=123920), you can open a new session (=tab) by sending a `qdbus` command. The problem with this is that you need to run that command in a shell inside the konsole window, otherwise the environment variables will not be set. Now you could bind the following command to a keyboard shortcut in bash using `bind`:

```bsh
qdbus $KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE $KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW newSession "[profile_name]"
```

...but using `bind` is not really user friendly and especially not shell independent. Alternatively, you can specify an alias if that is acceptable.

If you want to have a keyboard shortcut that is independent from the shell you are currently using, you'll need to use a global shortcut and inevitably lose the environment variables.

### Using a global keyboard shortcut

The process depends on the `"Run all Konsole windows in a single process"` setting in `"Settings -> Configure Konsole"`.

#### All windows in one process

If that is enabled, there will be one qdbus service called `org.kde.konsole` and each window will be an object `Windows/1`, `Windows/2` etc. So if you only use one konsole window, the following command would be sufficient for a global keyboard shortcut:

```bsh
qdbus org.kde.konsole Windows/1 newSession "[profile_name]"
```

#### One process for each window

If konsole is configured to spawn a new process for each window, you'll have some additional options. In that case, there will be one qdbus service for each window called `org.kde.konsole-[process_id]`, each with only one object `Windows/1`.

To retrieve the id of the process owning the konsole window, we can use `xdotool`. In each of the following examples, replace `[profile_name]` with your profile's name:

**open new tab in active konsole window**

```bsh
qdbus org.kde.konsole-$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid) /Windows/1 newSession "[profile_name]"
```

**open new tab in most recently used (or active) konsole window**

```bsh
qdbus org.kde.konsole-$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool search --class "konsole" | tail -1)) /Windows/1 newSession "[profile_name]"
```

**open new tab in most recently used (or active) konsole window and bring it to front**

```bsh
qdbus org.kde.konsole-$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool search --class "konsole" | tail -1)) /Windows/1 newSession "[profile_name]"; xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool search --class "konsole" | tail -1)
```

Comment: Thanks danzel for this, won't get a chance to try this out till the new week; though I was hoping that it was a little more "built in". Like yourself, though, I had noticed that the behaviour has changed over the years; surprised that just didn't leave the option for both.